# Required String

Tags: java

Want `java.lang.String` but it is returning an array type, how to resolve this problem?

```
String actionFilms = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getString(R.string.hom));

expandableListData.put(filmGenres.get(0), actionFilms);
```

Comment: please share your string file. where home declare

Comment: You want a `String`, then don't try to convert into a `List` THE `String`. you want... `String actionFilms = context.getResources().getString(R.string.hom);` **You don't understand what you are doing here !**

Comment: @yuahi Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should. `java.util.Arrays.asList()` returns a List, not a String. If you want a String use `toString()`.

```
String actionFilms = 
     Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getString(R.string.hom)).toString();
```

Or as [AxelH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391450/axelh) suggests don't convert it to a List.

```
String actionFilms = context.getResources().getString(R.string.hom);
```

Comment: or OP can simply get the `String` directly without adding some `[ ]` from `List.toString` by remove the `Arrays.asList` call.